# MongoDB query to find documents whose field value is contained in a given string

Tags: mongodb

I have a string, say "string", and a field in a collection, say "name".

I would like to find all the documents whose name is a substring of "string" (it would return for example documents whose name is "str").

I have looked on internet, and I only find the reciprocal, that is for example documents whose name is "string2".

Would someone know please ?

KR
Zlotz

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: 4.2.8. Why do you ask ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no arbitrary substring match operator in MongDB that I know of, but you could try expressing your condition with [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) or [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

Comment: $where seems to have performance problems (it "requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection").

Comment: That's right, the operation you are trying to perform is not very efficient.

Comment: And how could $regex be used (I can see how to search field values as "overstrings", but not as substrings)

Comment: `/a(b(c?))?|((a?)b)?c/` gets you prefixes or suffixes of `abc`.

Comment: OK, but my "overstring" is a PHP variable. I guess that I have to create a PHP function to generate the regex. But it's OK, I have to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I wanted to achieve the same in my project query below worked for me

```
db.find({name:{ $regex: new RegExp("^" + "your string pattern".toLowerCase(), "i") } })
```

Let me know if you find it useful.